# React Native Elements Theme Provider not working?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm pretty sure I'm using this according to the instructions but the text isn't changing:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { ThemeProvider, Text } from "react-native-elements";
import Customer from "../models/Customer";

class CustomerScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Text h1>{customer.fullName}</Text>
          <Text>{customer.email}</Text>
          <Text>{customer.phone}</Text>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 20,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start"
  }
};

const theme = {
  Text: {
    color: "red"
  }
};

export default CustomerScreen;
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: i am guessing you are not supposed to enclose the `<ThemeProvider>` with the outer `<View>`. have you tried removing it?

Comment: That's a great thought, but I've tried putting the View inside the ThemeProvider (instead of vice versa) with no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it working by nesting it under `style` like this:

```
const theme = {
  Text: {
    style: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
};
```

i am not very familiar with `<ThemeProvider>` and its [documentation](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/text.html#docsNav) doesn't clearly indicate that `<Text>` styling is to be under the `style` props. you may have to experiment further with it. :)

Comment: Ugh! Duh! That's it. Thanks.